# R : lines are not visible in plot

Tags: r, plot

I have a vector named `anomaly`  which gives the output :

```
 anomaly
 [1] -0.11 -0.13 -0.01 -0.04 -0.42 -0.23 -0.25 -0.45 -0.23  0.04 -0.22 -0.55
[13] -0.40 -0.39 -0.32 -0.32 -0.27 -0.15 -0.21 -0.25 -0.05 -0.05 -0.30 -0.35
[25] -0.42 -0.25 -0.15 -0.41 -0.30 -0.31 -0.21 -0.25 -0.33 -0.28 -0.02  0.06
[37] -0.20 -0.46 -0.33 -0.09 -0.15 -0.04 -0.09 -0.16 -0.11 -0.15  0.04 -0.05
[49]  0.01 -0.22 -0.03  0.03  0.04 -0.11  0.05 -0.08  0.01  0.12  0.15 -0.02
[61]  0.14  0.11  0.10  0.06  0.10 -0.01  0.01  0.12 -0.03 -0.09 -0.17 -0.02
[73]  0.03  0.12 -0.09 -0.09 -0.18  0.08  0.10  0.05 -0.02  0.10  0.05  0.03
[85] -0.25 -0.15 -0.07 -0.02 -0.09  0.00  0.04 -0.10 -0.05  0.18 -0.06 -0.02
[97] -0.21  0.16  0.07  0.13  0.27  0.40  0.10  0.34  0.16  0.13  0.19  0.35
[109]  0.42  0.28  0.49  0.44  0.16  0.18  0.31  0.47  0.36  0.40  0.71  0.43
[121]  0.41  0.56  0.70  0.66  0.60
```

Also have a vector named `MA`  which gives the output :

```
  MA
  [1] -8.333333e-02 -6.000000e-02 -1.566667e-01 -2.300000e-01 -3.000000e-01
  [6] -3.100000e-01 -3.100000e-01 -2.133333e-01 -1.366667e-01 -2.433333e-01
 [11] -3.900000e-01 -4.466667e-01 -3.700000e-01 -3.433333e-01 -3.033333e-01
 [16] -2.466667e-01 -2.100000e-01 -2.033333e-01 -1.700000e-01 -1.166667e-01
 [21] -1.333333e-01 -2.333333e-01 -3.566667e-01 -3.400000e-01 -2.733333e-01
 [26] -2.700000e-01 -2.866667e-01 -3.400000e-01 -2.733333e-01 -2.566667e-01
 [31] -2.633333e-01 -2.866667e-01 -2.100000e-01 -8.000000e-02 -5.333333e-02
 [36] -2.000000e-01 -3.300000e-01 -2.933333e-01 -1.900000e-01 -9.333333e-02
 [41] -9.333333e-02 -9.666667e-02 -1.200000e-01 -1.400000e-01 -7.333333e-02
 [46] -5.333333e-02 -5.782412e-19 -8.666667e-02 -8.000000e-02 -7.333333e-02
 [51]  1.333333e-02 -1.333333e-02 -6.666667e-03 -4.666667e-02 -6.666667e-03
 [56]  1.666667e-02  9.333333e-02  8.333333e-02  9.000000e-02  7.666667e-02
 [61]  1.166667e-01  9.000000e-02  8.666667e-02  5.000000e-02  3.333333e-02
 [66]  4.000000e-02  3.333333e-02  0.000000e+00 -9.666667e-02 -9.333333e-02
 [71] -5.333333e-02  4.333333e-02  2.000000e-02 -2.000000e-02 -1.200000e-01
 [76] -6.333333e-02  4.625929e-18  7.666667e-02  4.333333e-02  4.333333e-02
 [81]  4.333333e-02  6.000000e-02 -5.666667e-02 -1.233333e-01 -1.566667e-01
 [86] -8.000000e-02 -6.000000e-02 -3.666667e-02 -1.666667e-02 -2.000000e-02
 [91] -3.666667e-02  1.000000e-02  2.333333e-02  3.333333e-02 -9.666667e-02
 [96] -2.333333e-02  6.666667e-03  1.200000e-01  1.566667e-01  2.666667e-01
 [101]  2.566667e-01  2.800000e-01  2.000000e-01  2.100000e-01  1.600000e-01
 [106]  2.233333e-01  3.200000e-01  3.500000e-01  3.966667e-01  4.033333e-01
 [111]  3.633333e-01  2.600000e-01  2.166667e-01  3.200000e-01  3.800000e-01
 [116]  4.100000e-01  4.900000e-01  5.133333e-01  5.166667e-01  4.666667e-01
 [121]  5.566667e-01  6.400000e-01  6.533333e-01




  summary(MA)
     Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
  -0.44670 -0.16330 -0.03667 -0.01051  0.08500  0.65330 

 summary(anomaly)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-0.55000 -0.18000 -0.02000 -0.00632  0.12000  0.71000
```

There is also a vector `year` which takes value from 1880 to 2004 .

My intention is to plot `anomaly`  and `MA` in the same figure . So i wrote down the code :

```
 plot(anomaly,col="red",xlim=c(1880,2004),ylim=c(-.6,.75),xlab="year",ylab="anomaly",main="Anomaly , 5-year Moving Average")

lines(anomaly,col="red")
lines(MA,col="green")

text(1978,.60,"Original data",col="red")
text(1978,.50,"5-year Moving Average",col="green")
```

But the graph doesn't produce the lines .

[image]

Why are the lines invisible ?

Comment: Can you add your two data sets using dput, rather than an image?  it help people reproduce your problem and provide solutions.

Comment: From your plot and lines command it is not clear that x-axis is "year", while your xlim is set to this range. Change plot in something like : `plot(year, anomaly)`.

Comment: @RuthgerRighart Thank you . Now only the red graph is visible . But still `lines` are not working .

Comment: You should do the same with your lines command: `lines(year, anomaly)`

Comment: @RuthgerRighart Thank you again .But in `lines (year, MA, col="green")` , the length of  year and MA differ. But i can't increase the length of MA , also need to plot it in the same graph to make comparison.  Is there any way ?

Comment: Do you mean vector length (i.e., `length(MA)`) or do you mean the range of values, `ylim`? Vector lengths should be identical for year, anomaly, MA. Ylim can be set for both anomaly and MA sothat the min and max values are displayed for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you already have answers for including `year` in your calls to `plot` and `lines`. To keep the data all the same length, there are a couple of ways that I would try. My preferred method is to use a data.frame, since it appears your data are certainly tied to `year`:

```
dat <- data.frame(year, anomaly, MA)
```

The code to plot it below relies on this, but if you want to continue using individual vectors then you can continue with your own code by using code like this (generalized in case your data lengths will change, in which case you might want to check the length of `anomaly` as well).

```
if (length(MA) != length(year))
    MA <- c(MA, rep(NA, length(year) - length(MA)))
```

The code to plot. I made a few changes, heavily based on my programming OCD :-)

- Avoiding the use of "magic constants" in my code; imagine if you wanted to change the color of your anomalies at some point, you'd need to change it to the same in two locations. This is minor but when your plots get more complex, this can be a life-saver.
- Using formulas for `plot` and `lines` (taking advantage of the data.frame). This doesn't necessarily improve the readability of the code that much (it's still obvious which is on which axis), but I think it's slightly easier to read `(MA ~ year, data=dat, ...)` vice `(dat$year, dat$MA, ...)`. Very slightly.

Code:

```
colAnomaly <- 'red'
colMovAvg <- 'green'
plot(anomaly ~ year, data=dat, type='l', col=colAnomaly,
     xlim=c(1880,2004), ylim=c(-.6,.75),
     xlab="year", ylab="anomaly", main="Anomaly , 5-year Moving Average")
lines(MA ~ year, data=dat, col=colMovAvg)
text(1978, 0.60, "Original data", col=colAnomaly)
text(1978, 0.50, "5-year Moving Average", col=colMovAvg)
```